# Control Page Break in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a table which contain hundred of columns for the table and I would like to create multi pages to display each single record in SSRS.

Can you advise how to add page break . I have search all of solution and also find the union SQL , it seem doesn't help, I give the below example and expect output for your reference

Report Table structure as below
Column1
Column2
Column3
.
Column99

I want the report layout is  
Record : 1
Column1 : Column1.Value
Column2 : Column2.Value
Column3 : Column3.Value
Column4 : Column4.Value
-----  page break -----
Record : 1
Column4 : Column4.Value
Column5 : Column5.Value
Column6 : Column6.Value
Column7 : Column7.Value
-----  page break -----
Record : 1
Column85 : Column85.Value
Column89 : Column89.Value

-----  page break -----
Record : 2
Column1 : Column1.Value
Column2 : Column2.Value
Column3 : Column3.Value
Column4 : Column4.Value

-----  page break -----
Record : 2
Column4 : Column4.Value
Column5 : Column5.Value
Column6 : Column6.Value
Column7 : Column7.Value

-----  page break -----
Record : 2
Column85 : Column85.Value
Column89 : Column89.Value

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you would want to use `RowNumber` but it's a little unclear what your issue is.  What have to tried that hasn't worked?

Comment: No, I want to Report Builder to make a letter form (like a mail merge) but each record need 3 pages and each page need to add page break, I have tried to add rectangle under tablix inner group row. it also not working

Comment: Hi I final find the problem, if I add column in tablix , Page break in rectangle is not work